# Store website URL hit count in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to keep a record of pages requested by users. Additionally, I have to store count of each page requested. I am currently storing my website page visits of users by updating an index in elastic search.
I do this by updating a document which is similar to

```
{
    userid : 'id1234',
    url : 'website.com/url-1',
    count : 23,
}
```

Here, count of '23' is the total number of time the URL was requested by user with id 'id1234'.

To achieve this, I retrieve the document, increment the present count, and re-push again. My questions is that is it possible to do this with a single query?
I saw a similar approach using scripts [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).
Can we do this without scripts?

Comment: You're trying to use ElasticSearch as a database. Sure you can *technically* do that but the real question is why not use something more suited for this particular task like a normal database or a simple key-value store?

Comment: I can understand your point. Our use-case involves features that require ES.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is not well suited for Updates. So, even if it was possible to do an update like this, it was first deleting the record, then adding it (the whole document) and reindexing.

Probably the closest thing here is using partial update feature:

Here is an example from a documentation:

```
POST /metrics/users/1/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.count+=1"
}
```

But you've mentioned it in the question ( The link to the relevant document is available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html))

But if you were using scripts, the problem still is that it's relatively slow

Comment: I did like this approach of using _script_ but there I guess you would need document id beforehand. Also, I want to avoid the search step. Basically, I want to send out a single update request to ES with a query on _user_ and _url_ fields.

Comment: Latency is not a problem right now since it would be ~1sec I guess.

Comment: It's not only about latency (although using other databases for this task could be way faster) but about an amount of work that ElasticSearch has to do to support this, given its internal structure which is far from being used in "regular" databases. So an attempt to use it as a database is kind of wrong approach. Now as for searching the doc - its not a problem, you can search the document once (during the startup of the application and keep this id in a cache it won't change anyway). Searching is really fast in ES unlike updates.

Comment: I can see your concern in using ES as a database. Well, we will be going for scheduled updates to ES. Live updates will be done to cache or in-memory DB. As for using ES for this work, we would further use this kind of data to create aggregations and kibana charts for analytics. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Oh, if this is for metrics - consider time series approach like its done in metering. I know its possible to store metrics in ES as well, and kibana supports this, but the changes are that every time a new metrics is submitted, a new document is written to the document and then use aggregations to read this value. This value you'll be able to see "historical perspective" as well, for example to measure rates and see whether now the rate has increased compared to the rate before an hour. This will allow building realtime graphs.

Comment: Old metrics can be removed automatically or manually depending on technology (ES I think doesn't have built-in TTLs for indexes - was removed in 5.0). Another cool option is using Prometheus + Grafana which can also show beautiful metrics, support tags, etc. In the application there is no reason to build "metering reporter" by yourself - there are ready solutions. For example in Java its a library called Micrometer or (slightly older, without tags - Dropwizard Metrics), in other languages similar solutions exist.

Comment: Cool!! Would explore these too. You mentioned the time series approach. How would that be different from the current approach of updating JSONs. If you could point me to the relevant links it would be great.

Comment: Its different because db stores all the values over time, not only a current value. Since this is insert only data (no updates and deletes of single values) db engines can be highly optimized for this. As for links, google for prometheus and grafana. Other options are influx db (tick stack), data dog, graphite...

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into these.